# How can I convert a ByteArray to an Int with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, type-conversion

How can I convert a ByteArray to an Int with Kotlin?

The code I was using in Java :

```
return ((buffer[offset++] & 0xff) << 24) |
       ((buffer[offset++] & 0xff) << 16) |
       ((buffer[offset++] & 0xff) << 8) |
       (buffer[offset] & 0xff);
```

I tried this code in Kotlin :

```
return (buffer[offset++] and 0xff shl 24) or
       (buffer[offset++] and 0xff shl 16) or
       (buffer[offset++] and 0xff shl 8) or
       (buffer[offset] and 0xff)
```

But it returns the following warning regarding the "and" operator :

> None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver
> type mismatch

Comment: if i replace `buffer[offset++]` with the value `1`, i don't seem to be getting any warnings or errors, might be that there's something wrong with your buffer (or the type inside the buffer) perhaps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some reading, seems like Bitwise operations like `and`, `or`, and `shl` are only defined for Int and Long in Kotlin.

from the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#operations):

[image]

You'll have to convert these if you want to use them

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @a_local_nobody, I managed to fix the problem :

```
return (buffer[offset++].toInt() and 0xff shl 24) or
        (buffer[offset++].toInt() and 0xff shl 16) or
        (buffer[offset++].toInt() and 0xff shl 8) or
        (buffer[offset].toInt() and 0xff)
```

Comment: ahh, beat me to it :)